# Intermediate and advanced Esperanto learning books (lernolibroj)

Tags: learning, resources, books

Are there any intermediate to advanced level Esperanto learning books or ebooks? Most seem to apply to beginners. For those that have mastered the basics, however there seems to be a lack of books, especially ones with exercises (and their answers).

Ĉu estas meznivelaj aŭ altnivelaj Esperanto lernolibroj aŭ bitlibroj? La plejparte bonas nur por komencantoj. Por tiuj kiuj jam scias la fundamentojn, ne ŝajnas esti tro multe da libroj, precipe enhavantaj ekzercojn (kaj respondojn).

**Update:**
Apart from the several good suggestions in the answers below, I found a couple more books. The first is "La Tuta Esperanto", by Henrik Seppik, a grammar focusing on practical usage cases (https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Tuta_Esperanto, available at http://denizo.opia.dk/la.trezorejo/instruiloj/kurso.seppik.la.tuta.eo.1937.zip). The other is "Paŝoj al Plena Posedo" (https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pa%C5%9Doj_al_Plena_Posedo). Both are intermediate level, with exercises (not solutions, however) and very helpful.

**Ĝisdatigo:**
Krom la bonaj sugestoj en la subaj respondoj, mi trovis du aliajn librojn. La unua estas "La Tuta Esperanto", de Henrik Seppik, gramatiklibro pri praktika lingvuzado (https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Tuta_Esperanto, trovita ĉe http://denizo.opia.dk/la.trezorejo/instruiloj/kurso.seppik.la.tuta.eo.1937.zip). La alia estas "Paŝoj al Plena Posedo" (https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pa%C5%9Doj_al_Plena_Posedo). Ambaŭ estas mezniveloj, enhavas ekzercojn (tamen ne solvojn) kaj mi trovas ilin tre helpemaj.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried *Being Colloquial in Esperanto*? It doesn't contain exercises, but it goes a bit deeper than the beginner level books. There are physical copies available, I believe, but below I will attach a link to the electronic version.

http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq003-Contents.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: I have read most of it already, sometime ago, yes. A great suggestion, I'll go back to it. thanks! (and for those looking for the same thing, I also recommend it, with the "no excercises" caveat)

Answer (score 4):

> Recommendations for post-beginners. After you've worked your way
>   through your first Esperanto textbook, readers, or online courses,
>   you'll be ready for some more advanced reading material.

http://esperanto-usa.org/en/node/1511

Comment: Nice list. I'll look into them!

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I’ve written a number of short articles in intermediate/advanced Esperanto, on a variety of topics, such as the surprising similarities between P. G. Wodehouse and F. D. Roosevelt. The articles are all in the Public Domain, and you can access them [here](http://www.public-domain-materials.com/dosierujo-artikoloj-en-esperanto.html): http://www.public-domain-materials.com/dosierujo-artikoloj-en-esperanto.html

Answer (score 3):

The book [*Vojaĝo en Esperanto-lando*](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voja%C4%9Do_en_Esperanto-lando) by Boris Kolker is a book designed to bring intermediate learners to an advanced level of Esperanto, such that they will not only be able to read anything, but also to write with good style, as well as learn more about Esperanto culture and history, and some general knowledge. It contains literature of various kinds (stories, poetry, etc) from a variety of authors (including, of course, Zamenhof, Piron, and other famous authors), as well as exercises. There was a correspondence course called "[Internacia Perfektiga Koresponda Kurso](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internacia_Perfektiga_Koresponda_Kurso)" based on the book, but unfortunately I can no longer find it; all I can find are dead links. It was a somewhat expensive course; perhaps not enough people bought it to keep it going. But at least the book is still [available from UEA](http://katalogo.uea.org/katalogo.php?inf=4296) :-).

The book is written entirely in Esperanto, so a basic reading understanding is assumed.

Comment: I found the link I had seen before: http://www.esperanto-mv.pp.ru/Vojagxo/index.html ; it contains a few sample lessons, and Sr-o Kolker's contact info (supposing it's still current), but nothing about the price of the course, if it's still available.

Answer (score 2):

For those that have mastered the basics, there's no need in learning books. Esperanto is such an easy language, that after working through "Fundamento" you can and definitely should start reading original, not adapted literature. That will let you quickly build up vocabulary (word stock).

Comment: Indeed reading more (and better) is a great way to move forward. Alas, at least for my learning style, sobre more didactic texts to help systematize grammar and the like (not only vocabulary) would help. For me, at least, it is very different to be able to understand a text (I'm managing that fairly easily) and writing it. Hence my search for something with excercises.